# How to receive number of bytes

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimagepickercontroller

i am developing a video app in which i want to receive number of bytes when user is recording the video(not after).But there is no delegate method that runs when user is recording video.

```
- (void) imagePickerController: (UIImagePickerController*) reader
 didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo: (NSDictionary*) info
```

is called after user picks it.so can any one help me out of the problem.

Comment: ya.but problem is not resolved yet.

Comment: @haigowtham It's inappropriate to repeat your questions. The proper thing to do is to update your original question if needed.

Comment: You tried my answer? He's incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use this code to get number of bytes from NSData:

NSData *data=@"Your Data";

```
    const unsigned char *bytes = [data bytes]; 
    NSUInteger length = [data length];
    NSMutableArray *byteArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        [byteArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithUnsignedChar:bytes[i]]];
    }
```

the byteArray count will have the count of your bytes.

Comment: but in which delegate method should i write this code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380751/detecting-when-user-starts-video-recording...have look on this

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sample.png"];
 NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(img, 0); 
 NSLog(@"Size of Image(bytes):%d",[imgData length]);
```